# How to know which custom site template is used by site using javascript object model?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

At SharePoint Online I have created 100 subsites using two 'custom site templates'.

- Personal site template and
- Business site template.

Now I want to categorize and show these subsites as `Personal Subsites` and `Business Subsites` within web part.

So for that, I want the site template name which is used by subsite using javascript object model. I googled a lot but not found anything.

**Note:** I have tried global variable `g_wsaSiteTemplateId` and `web.get_webTemplate()` but it giving base template name. ie `STS#0`, But I want Personal OR Business.

Is it possible? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure tbh if there is a value stored someplace, but I guess you could check the features activated. If its a custom template created inside SharePoint there should be features with names like "PersonalModules", "BusinessModules".

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var feats = ctx.get_web().get_features();
ctx.load(feats, "Include(DisplayName)");

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 

    // just for debug   
    feats.get_data().forEach(function(e) {      
        console.log( e.get_displayName() );
    }); 

    var templateName = "Personal";
    console.log( !!feats.get_data().filter(function(e) { return e.get_displayName() == templateName+"Modules"}).length );   

});
```

Comment: I tried this but there are no such features as our template names.

Comment: @VishalM.Patil you did check in the console and not in the GUI, since the features does not show in the GUI. I checked 3 custom templates, and they all had name+"Module"

Comment: Yes Anders...I checked in console and there lots of features are listed but but no such feature listed in it...Are you tried it on SharePoint online?

Comment: @VishalM.Patil yes, checked another tenant too now, same there. Have a template with the name "Projecttemplate", and the feature is named "ProjecttemplateModules" there

Comment: Ohk...these features are in  site collection features of root site. not a site features(subsite). But with these approach how can i  identity current site is personal or business?